# ¿Cómo sacar el primer número de una variable en PHP?

Tags: php

Suponemos estas variables que contienen enlaces:

```
$enlace1 = 'miweb.com/blog/post/9/Hola-123';

$enlace2 = 'miweb.com/blog/post/4938/Los-10-mejores-posts';
```

Tengo que establecer una función que me permita conocer el ID del post (el primer número que está entre `/  /`. De modo que me tiene que dar:

```
extraer_ID($enlace1); // resultado deseado: 9
extraer_ID($enlace2); // resultado deseado: 4938
```

De momento esto es lo que he hecho:

```
function extraer_ID ($enlace)
{
    return filter_var($enlace, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}

extraer_ID($enlace1); // resultado: 9123
extraer_ID($enlace2); // resultado: 493810
```

El resultado me da mal porque incluye todos los números del enlace y solamente necesito el primer número.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `preg_match` de la siguiente manera:

```
preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $enlace1, $resultado);
```

donde el primer parámetro será la regex en la cual buscas un dígito, el segundo parámetro será el `string` en el cual quieres buscar y el tercer parámetro la variable donde se almacenará el resultado.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

    $enlace1 = 'miweb.com/blog/post/9/Hola-123';
    $enlace2 = 'miweb.com/blog/post/4938/Los-10-mejores-posts';

    preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $enlace1, $resultado);
    preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $enlace2, $resultado2);

    echo $resultado[0] . "\n"; 
    echo $resultado2[0];
```

Y dará como resultado:

```
9
4938
```

**[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70ee84d3a22434bcf4dd393ccfa461e00173f760)**.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que todos los enlaces que quieras sacar el id son de la misma manera, o tienen el mismo formato, puedes usar la funcion explode, y obtener la posicion del arreglo resultante, algo asi:

```
<?php

$enlace1 = 'miweb.com/blog/post/9/Hola-123';
$enlace2 = 'miweb.com/blog/post/4938/Los-10-mejores-posts';

$a = explode("/",$enlace1);
$b = explode("/",$enlace2);

$id_a = $a[3]; // guarda 9
$id_b = $b[3]; // guarda 4983
```

Y haciendo una función quedaria:

```
function extraer_ID ($enlace, $posicion){
    $r = explode("/",$enlace);
    return $r[$posicion];
}

$a = extraer_ID($enlace1, 3);
$b = extraer_ID($enlace2, 3);
```

En el codigo anterior coloco el parametro posicion para obtener algun otro elemento del enlace si fuera necesario.

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e39dda978aba7b8cecfc8ae1a1b8b69c2ab351b5)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta!